# Rails: UrlHelpers in js.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sprockets

I want to keep things dry, so I'm thinking of creating a config file and put there all urls, etc.. It should be something like:

```
# configure.js.erb
some_url = <%= some_url.inspect %>
```

But there's a problem: url's hlper methods aren't included by default. I've already tried:

```
# config/initialializer/sprockets_js_erb.rb
module Sprockets::Rails::Helpers
  include ::Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

That broke the all method, setting the internal `_routes` to `nil` and raising an error when call `_routes.optimize_routes_generation?` in `lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:167` (and I don't know why)

There's a clean solution to this problems? Thanks

---

**EDIT**
Ok, I've just changed to `class Sprockets::Context` and it works, but I'm still searching for a better solution, whishfull ones that alters `ERBTemplate`'s `Context` only :)